# i am getting an error - The name 'Vector2' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am making a project in unity....
I am getting an error:

> The name Vector 2 does not exist in the current context

what should I do?

my code is:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class paddle : MonoBehaviour
{


    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float moveSpeed;


     private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    void TouchMove() 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);


            if(touchPos.x < 0)
            {
                //move left
                rb.velocity = Vector2.left * moveSpeed;
            }
            else if(touchPos.x > 0)
            {
                //move right
                rb.velocity = Vector2.right * moveSpeed;

            }


        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = vector2.zero;
        }


    } 


}
```

Comment: using UnityEngine.CoreModule; helps?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy from memory, I believe the *namespace* is just `UnityEngine` (which is already declared), and the *package* is `UnityEngine.CoreModule`

Comment: pro tip: indicating **exactly** which line it fails on is important, and telling us **exactly** what the message is: is important. I am 100% sure that the error message doesn't say "The name Vector 2 does not exist in the current context", because the compiler would never add a whitespace ("Vector 2"). So: that means we can't trust your message. What **exactly** does it say? (copy and paste it - do **not** re-type it)

Answer (score 0):

`vector2.zero` should probably be `Vector2.zero` - **case matters**